# Putting two <ul>'s next to each other

Tags: html, css, html-lists, inline

I'm having some trouble with putting two `ul`'s next to each other.

```css
div.container > nav > ul > li > div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 13px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px #222222 solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul {
  width: 200px;
  border-left: 2px #555555 solid;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li {
  padding: 3px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > h4 {
  width: 242px;
  color: #d60000;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d60000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Website</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Basic</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Premium</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Without Hosting</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Without Database</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Multiple Website's</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Hosting</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Hosting</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Host a personal site</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Host an existing website</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem that I'm getting now is that the `<ul>`'s drop down under each other, where I like them to be `inline`.

Has anyone a proper solution for the problem. I searched through other's questions about this topic, all methods did not work.

Comment: is this a drop down menu??

Comment: Dude, those selectors are way too complex. `element.class > element > element > element > element > element > element` is a bunch of bad practices. Also, the CSS you provide doesn't match the HTML. Finally, for your problem you can probably use `float`, but please edit your code first so we can work with it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 method:
you need 2 div

```
<div>
    <h4>Website</h4>
     <ul>
     <li>
         <a href=''>Basic</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href=''>Premium</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 <div>
    <h4>Hosting</h4>
      <ul>
           <li>
             <a href=''>Hosting</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href=''>Host a personal site</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Css

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;

}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d2q6kbnw/

2nd method, make your h and ul tag into inline tag using css...

```
display:inline-block; float:left;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It works flawlessly. The second method didn't/doen't work by the way.

Comment: Welcome j van amerongen :)

Comment: 2nd method will work, but i see you are beginner, so you need extra effort, to do this, or you need some more help :)  , it will not work with only this 2 line css, but some more css according to your design.... keep continue learing, you will learn :) and be a good programmer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each `ul` into a parent `div` and apply `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top;` to them.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uompg/0hkmfamo/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the headling/list groups in a div and float them left:

```css
div.container > nav > ul > li > div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 13px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px #222222 solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul {
  width: 200px;
  border-left: 2px #555555 solid;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li {
  padding: 3px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > h4 {
  width: 242px;
  color: #d60000;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d60000;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h4>Website</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Basic</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Premium</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Without Hosting</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Without Database</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Multiple Website's</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <h4>Hosting</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Hosting</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Host a personal site</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=''>Host an existing website</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: was just about to post this

Answer (score 1):

You create 2 div "left" and "right" :

```
<div class="left">
 <h4>title</h4>
 <ul>...<ul>
</div>
<div class="right">
 <h4>title</h4>
 <ul>...<ul>
</div>

.left,
.right{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8o0z002f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
div.container > nav > ul > li > div {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px #222222 solid;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul {
    width: 200px;
    border-left: 2px #555555 solid;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li {
padding: 3px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > h4 {
    width: 242px;
    color: #d60000;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 12px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #d60000;
}

div ul{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>

  <ul>
    <h4>Website</h4>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Basic</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Premium</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Without Hosting</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Without Database</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Multiple Website's</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <h4>Hosting</h4>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Hosting</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Host a personal site</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Host an existing website</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/96/)**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `h4` tags are block level elements.  You would need to two wrap both lists in some sort of column `div` like so for the desired behavior:

```css
div.container > nav > ul > li > div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 13px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px #222222 solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul {
  width: 200px;
  border-left: 2px #555555 solid;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li {
  padding: 3px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > h4 {
  width: 242px;
  color: #d60000;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div.container > nav > ul > li > div > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d60000;
}
div.column {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="column">
  <h4>Website</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Basic</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Premium</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Without Hosting</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Without Database</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Multiple Website's</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div> 
  <div class="column">
  <h4>Hosting</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Hosting</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Host a personal site</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=''>Host an existing website</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```